# Why does Django log out a user after login() after redirect

Tags: django, django-views, wagtail

I am using Django and Wagtail but I think this is more specifically a Django problem.  When someone needs to reset their password because they have forgotten it I email them out an activation link.  The problem is that even though the activation link passes and I login them in with django.contrib.auth.login as soon as I redirect them to another page they are logged out again.

I have tried setting SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False but this has made no difference for me.  I am using Django 2.2 and Wagtail 2.8.  This is happening on both my development server (python manage.py runserver) and the production uwsgi server.

I've been pulling my hair out over this one so if any bright person can point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
    @route(r'^activate/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/$')
    def activate(self, request, uidb64, token):
        try:  
            uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))  
            user = get_user_model().objects.get(id=uid)  
        except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, get_user_model().DoesNotExist):  
            user = None  

        if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):  

            login(request, user)
            url = self.url + self.reverse_subpage('password_change', args=(user.pk,))
            return redirect(url) # weirdly logs out the user immediately 
        else:  
            return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')
```

Comment: I think the login should not be implemented in this view, rather in user password reset view

Comment: Why would that affect django redirect and cause it to lose the session?

Comment: does it even log in the first place? did you check with request.user.is_authenticated?